# Truncating our multiple line text fields inside our list views using JSLINK

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, development, list-view, jslink

I am working on an online sharepoint custom list. and we are rendering our list inside the classic UI. now inside the custom list's list view we have 3 fields of type multiple line of text. And if the users enter long text inside these list fields, the list view will become hard to track. as a single item inside the list view can consume the whole screen. so i find this JSLINK to truncate the data :-
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-code-93e7077d
, now i tested it inside our list and it was able to truncate the multiple line of text, here is the script:-

```
(function () { 
 
    // Create object that have the context information about the field that we want to change it's output render  
    var bodyFiledContext = {}; 
    bodyFiledContext.Templates = {}; 
    bodyFiledContext.Templates.Fields = { 
        // Apply the new rendering for Body field on list view 
        "CustomerFeedback": { "View": bodyFiledTemplate } 
    }; 
 
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(bodyFiledContext); 
 
})(); 
 
// This function provides the rendering logic 
function bodyFiledTemplate(ctx) { 
 
    var bodyValue = ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name]; 
 
    //This regex expression use to delete html tags from the Body field 
    var regex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig; 
 
    bodyValue = bodyValue.replace(regex, ""); 
 
    var newBodyValue = bodyValue; 
 
    if (bodyValue && bodyValue.length >= 200) 
    { 
        newBodyValue = bodyValue.substring(0, 200) + " ..."; 
    } 
 
    return "<span title='" + bodyValue + "'>" + newBodyValue + "</span>"; }
```

But i have these 2 issues:-

1. If the multiple line of text field contain for example bullets points or new line, then the truncated text + the tool-tip will ignore them. i think the truncate will just render plain text rather than a real HTML. so can i fix this issue inside the above script? now i tried to remove this `bodyValue = bodyValue.replace(regex, "");`, but this will result in showing the actual html source with its tags inside the tool-tip.
2. Second point, if i want to apply the truncate to 3 fields of type multiple-line of text, then can i do so inside the above script? or i have to load 3 multiple jslinks?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use JsLink? I succeeded on this in the past with CSS -->

thought I had to share, hope it helps you as a workaround

(this will truncate (but maybe not character wise) and then expand when you hover over it ;)

```
/*.ms-itmhover is the TR row*/
.ms-vb2  .ms-rtestate-field{
    min-width:200px;
    max-width:250px;
    max-height:50px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.ms-vb2  .ms-rtestate-field:hover{
    max-height:none;
}
```

Comment: yes i have to use JSLINK to customize the list view!! but what is the realtion between ur answer and my question...

Comment: You can still use jslink to customize the list view, The relationship to your questions is that if you use the CSS as a workaround you won't have to deal with the issues....

Comment: this will fix part of the issue.. and what abotu showing the full text as tool-tip?